# 'com.example.volleyexample.app.AppController' is not assignable to 'android.app.Activity'

Tags: android, xml, android-manifest

I don't know why this error comes

where to miss add some code or remove the code.

i'll just try to JSon Object Request

i'll take a 2 class `AppController` AND `LruBitmapCache`

Screen Shot of `Manifest.xml` :

[image]

activity_main.xml :

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Below code is a `AppController.java` class:

```
package com.example.volleyexample.app;

import android.app.Application;
import android.text.TextUtils;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.example.volleyexample.utils.LruBitmapCache;

public class AppController extends Application{

    public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
    private static AppController mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        getRequestQueue();
        if (mImageLoader == null) {
            mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(this.mRequestQueue,
                    new LruBitmapCache());
        }
        return this.mImageLoader;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        // set the default tag if tag is empty
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setTag(TAG);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: what is your package name ?

Comment: in main activity my package name : `com.example.volleyexample;` @Umair

Comment: Is AppController your activity's name? It looks like application's name

Comment: `AppController` is a java class @H.Ekici

Comment: @MohammadAli then you are giving a wrong package name. Remove .app from that then you will be fine.
com.example.volleyexample.AppController.

Comment: It could be a java class but which class does it extend?

Comment: sry is my fault @Umair my package name is `com.example.volleyexample.app;`

Comment: @MohammadAli You should add proper package name

Comment: @MohammadAli pls add your AppController class here ... :)

Comment: i'll understand your answer please give me a some time @IntelliJAmiya

Comment: your AppController class extends Application? Its not an acitivity. Its application class. You need to add it in <application tag

Comment: Let's check @Umair i'll update my question

Comment: it's extend `Aplication` @H.Ekici

Comment: @MohammadAli you are doing it wrong :) when you extend application class then you should declare it in <application tag of your manifest file.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya ya i'll check your answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You must add proper Package name with Activity name**.

[**`android:name`**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element)

> The name of the class that implements the activity, a subclass of
>   Activity. The attribute value should be a fully qualified class name
>   (such as, "com.example.project.ExtracurricularActivity"). However, as
>   a shorthand, if the first character of the name is a period (for
>   example, ".ExtracurricularActivity"), it is appended to the package
>   name specified in the  element.

You should add **Proper Package Name with Activity Name**.

```
<activity android:name="yourPackageName.ActivityName
```

**android:parentActivityName**

> The class name of the logical parent of the activity. The name here
>   must match the class name given to the corresponding 
>   element's **`android:name`** attribute.

**NOTE**

Your AppController is a **`Application`** class, So it should be  **`<application`** section.

**Finally**

```
<application
        android:name="com.example.volleyexample.app.AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
       >
        <activity
            android:name="
        >
```

Then **`Clean-Rebuild-Run`**.

Answer (score 1):

It should be in Application tag of manifest. Something like below

```
<application
        android:name=".yourPackage.AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

// Your activities, services... declared here

</application>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for a giving me a reply.. and it should be work for me..